# How to retrive and update radio button's data from mysql database?

Tags: php, mysql, insert, radio-button, edit

CODE am trying:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Male" <?php if ($type == 'Male') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>"> Male
```

OR

```
 <input type="radio" name="gender" value="<?php echo $gender ?>"/>Female
```

This one is right ??

i refer 2 links in SO but m not getting properly with radio button .... 
Suggestions always Welcome ...

Comment: what about update radio button's logic ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is correct:

```
<input type="radio" name="type" value="Male" <?php if ($type == 'Male') echo 'checked="checked"'; ?>"> Male
```

Comment: It's working great.....Thank u very much Sean sir & what about update logic because it's insert nothing ...